# react native firebase phone auth using play integrity

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, authentication, firebase-authentication

This is my code to authenticate using mobile number after pressing the button it sends the otp and sends it to recapta and then brings me back to my screen, what I want is that I want is after sending the number it should directly send otp to my message , after the new update they have depraceated the safetynet instead they use play integrity . anyone of you have solved this issue yet?

````
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, ScrollView,TouchableOpacity, Button, Pressable } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'

import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native'
import { responsiveFontSize, responsiveHeight, responsiveWidth } from 'react-native-responsive-dimensions';

import Ionicons from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";

import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

import PhoneInput from 'react-native-phone-number-input';

export default function PhoneAuth({ navigation }) {
  const [phonenumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('')
  console.log("phone number", phonenumber);
  const phoneInput = useRef(null);
  // If null, no SMS has been sent
  const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(null);

  // verification code (OTP - One-Time-Passcode)
  const [code, setCode] = useState('');

  const signInWithPhoneNumber = async phonenumber => {
    const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phonenumber);
    setConfirm(confirmation);
  }

  const confirmCode = async () => {
    try {
      await confirm.confirm(code);
      navigation.navigate("NavbarDrawer")
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Invalid code.');
    }
  }
  if (!confirm) {
    return (
      // <View style={{ marginTop: 100 }}>
      //   <TextInput style={{
      //     backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
      //     color: 'black',
      //   }}
      //     onChangeText={(phone) => setPhoneNumber(phone)}
      //     maxLength={13}
      //     // keyboardType='number-pad'
      //     placeholder='Enter +91 and your phone number'
      //     placeholderTextColor='black'
      //   />
      //   <Pressable style={{
      //     backgroundColor: 'red', marginTop: 20,
      //     justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: 50, margin: 100,
      //     borderRadius: 10
      //   }}>
      //     <Text onPress={()=>signInWithPhoneNumber(phonenumber)}>Sumbit</Text>
      //   </Pressable>
      // </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                backgroundColor: "#ff3333",
                borderRadius: responsiveWidth(5),
                alignItems: 'center',
                width: '77%',
                height:'10%',
                paddingVertical: '1%',
                marginTop: '4%',
                alignSelf: 'center',
                justifyContent:'center',
                alignItems:'center',
                marginTop:200
              }}
              onPress={() => signInWithPhoneNumber('+91 724-928-3143')}
            >
      <Text>Phone number sign in</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1, marginTop: 500 }}>
        <TextInput style={{ color: "black" }} value={code} onChangeText={text => setCode(text)} />
        <Button title="Confirm Code" onPress={() => confirmCode()} />

      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputphoneno: {
    borderRadius: responsiveWidth(3),
    color: "black",
    paddingHorizontal: '2%',
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    marginVertical: "3%",
    fontSize: responsiveFontSize(2.3),
    borderColor: "rgb(0,0, 0,0.2)",
    // borderWidth: responsiveWidth(0.13),
    zIndex: -1,
    borderBottomWidth: responsiveWidth(0.5),
    borderBottomColor: 'grey'

  },

  phoneContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    height: responsiveHeight(6.5),
    marginVertical: '4.5%'
  },

  textInput: {
    paddingVertical: '1%',
  },
})```


I tried downloading the dependencies and everything but I dont understand the docs moreover there is no video explaining it !
````

Comment: Have you found the solution ? I am always receiving following error from firebase 'This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that neither SafetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA checks succeeded'. I have added SHA-1 And SHA-256 in firebase app. Enabled 'Play integrity API'. And added following in app/build.gradle. implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.1.0'
    i

Comment: @user1927603 No bro I have skipped this issue because we solved it using back-end also I am not working on that project anymore!